"project.assets.json doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0'", but it does, and package restore was successful?
I have two simple console applications in a solution, and I am trying to build them using an azure devops build pipeline. They will build just fine on any laptop, but the azure devops build pipeline throws the following error (relevant excerpt):
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): Error NETSDK1005: 
Assets file 'F:\SomePath\MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: 
Assets file 'F:\SomePath\MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [F:\SomePath\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]

I don't understand this though, the csproj files of both projects contain the following line: <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
I have searched online for others having this problem, and other times this error has been posted, the suggestions are to perform a nuget restore, but I am already doing this: The previous step in the pipeline was a nuget restore, which runs successfully.
I'm not sure how to even begin trying to diagnose this, everything the error is referencing appears to be as it should be.

Please share the relevant part of the pipeline that allow us to reproduce the issue. Also, are you using Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted build agents?

self-hosted build agents. Exactly what part of the pipeline do you want? There isn't much fancy going on here: https://i.imgur.com/yCPsVH5.png

If you say They will build just fine on any laptop, but the azure devops build pipeline throws the following error... then the problem might be in the pipeline, so it might be useful to see all the tasks used to build the solution: install .NET, restore packages, build, etc.

You might be overestimating the complexity of the pipeline I am using. https://i.imgur.com/us9y8TD.png

Running dotnet sdk check on the server just to be absolutely certain, it does have the required version to perform this build: https://i.imgur.com/MMKLzka.png

According to the official documentation for NETSDK1005, the NuGet version should be higher than 5.8.
In your screenshot, it seems that you didn't specify the version of NuGet.
I can reproduce the issue when I created a simple Net8 console project and use the old NuGet version.

When I changed to use the NuGet 5.8, it works.


This was the issue; specifying the version fixed it. I don't understand why it would use an old version of nuget. I did try creating another new pipeline and it worked right away, so this seems quite inconsistent.
